# lodash recursively find item in array

Tags: javascript, recursion, lodash

What might be the easiest solution in lodash to recursively find item in array by, for example, 'text' field with value 'Item-1-5-2'?

```
const data = [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'Item-1',
        children: [
          { id: 11, text: 'Item-1-1' },
          { id: 12, text: 'Item-1-2' },
          { id: 13, text: 'Item-1-3' },
          { id: 14, text: 'Item-1-4' },
          {
            id: 15,
            text: 'Item-1-5',
            children: [
              { id: 151, text: 'Item-1-5-1' },
              { id: 152, text: 'Item-1-5-2' },
              { id: 153, text: 'Item-1-5-3' },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: 'Item-2',
        children: [
          { id: 21, text: 'Item-2-1' },
          { id: 22, text: 'Item-2-2' },
          { id: 23, text: 'Item-2-3' },
          { id: 24, text: 'Item-2-4' },
          { id: 25, text: 'Item-2-5' },
        ]
      },
      { id: 3, text: 'Item-3' },
      { id: 4, text: 'Item-4' },
      { id: 5, text: 'Item-5' },
    ];
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In plain Javascript, you could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) recursively.

```js
function getObject(array, key, value) {
    var o;
    array.some(function iter(a) {
        if (a[key] === value) {
            o = a;
            return true;
        }
        return Array.isArray(a.children) && a.children.some(iter);
    });
    return o;
}

var data = [{ id: 1, text: 'Item-1', children: [{ id: 11, text: 'Item-1-1' }, { id: 12, text: 'Item-1-2' }, { id: 13, text: 'Item-1-3' }, { id: 14, text: 'Item-1-4' }, { id: 15, text: 'Item-1-5', children: [{ id: 151, text: 'Item-1-5-1' }, { id: 152, text: 'Item-1-5-2' }, { id: 153, text: 'Item-1-5-3' }, ] }, ] }, { id: 2, text: 'Item-2', children: [{ id: 21, text: 'Item-2-1' }, { id: 22, text: 'Item-2-2' }, { id: 23, text: 'Item-2-3' }, { id: 24, text: 'Item-2-4' }, { id: 25, text: 'Item-2-5' }, ] }, { id: 3, text: 'Item-3' }, { id: 4, text: 'Item-4' }, { id: 5, text: 'Item-5' }, ];

console.log(getObject(data, 'text', 'Item-1-5-2'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Blowsie, a function which calls the same function ... please have a look to `iter`.

Comment: Exactly `getObject` does not call `getObject` therefore is not recursive.

Comment: but `iter` does.

Answer (score 7):

It's the perfect spot for a recursive function.

```
function findText(items, text) {
  if (!items) { return; }

  for (const item of items) {
    // Test current object
    if (item.text === text) { return item; }

    // Test children recursively
    const child = findText(item.children, text);
    if (child) { return child; }
  }
}
```

That's also the best way to get the maximum performances. Traversal is some in depth-first-search way.

Comment: This one works. TY :)